# I am trying to do a one to one match between two csv files. the name I type I want python to search the other csv file and spit out the matching name

Tags: python, list

So this is my code I am running:

```
import pandas as pd
import os


os.chdir("/Users/oliviaunokesan/")

#df=[df1, df2]
#idx=df['NAME']== 'Claustrum'
#print(df[idx])

#define query

def query(list_of_dfs, column, key):
    output= []
    for df in list_of_dfs:
        row= df[df[column]==key]
        output.append(row)
    return output

#uploaded csv files

df1= pd.read_csv("New_labels2.csv")
df2= pd.read_csv("human_ontology.csv")

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
idx=df['NAME']== 'Claustrum'
print(df[idx])

#print

print(df1)
print('')
print(df2)
print('')
print('')

#def terms

column='NAME'
key= 'Claustrum'
#list_of_dfs= query([df1, df2], column, key)

print('Results of query:')
rows= query([df1, df2], column, key)
print(rows)
```

I am expecting my code to search the human ontology file for the same name in the new labels 2 file. when I run my code it says (KeyError: 'Name') I am not sure why it keeps giving me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You evaluated `df["NAME"] == "Claustrum"` and were unhappy with the result:

The trouble is that `df` is a `list` rather than a `DataFrame`.

When you assigned `df = [df1, df2]`
what you were looking for is

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Comment: thank you but when I change it to that I now get a 'name' error

Comment: I understand. I have no idea what that pair of .CSV's contains. But your current program requires that each have a `NAME` column. If one or both do not, you will see that diagnostic error message.

Comment: only one of my csv files have that which is the "new labels2.csv". thank you for helping I will continue to play with my codes